# How to clean messy pdf with a list of tabular data that has no real delineator?

Tags: python, pandas, pdf

I have a pdf file that has a list of multiple tables of data.

[image]

I would like to separate out each table into it's own text file.

However, as you can see there are a two main issues:

- The data is split across multiple pages with each page having a page number
- Some of the data is linked so I'm not able to use something like space to separate it out

I have tried:

- Using py2pdf to firstly try and get the pdf into a text file format, but when reading with pandas the entire thing goes tits up.
- I have also tried using queries in excel
- Tabula doesn't seem to be able to read the tables because of the face that some numbers are joined

Is there any way to do this by firstly getting all the data (without page numbers) into a text file, then separating each table by title and then separating out each number using the number of digits after `.` ?

Comment: Hi Chloe! Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you mean by "Some of the data is linked"? Do you mean there's no gap between (say) the column 1 data and the column 2 data?

Comment: I think the tricky thing about answering a question like this is, you presumably have a pdf with lots of pages, but we only have one screenshot. It's tricky to generalise from one page of examples

Comment: Hi!, Yes, I mean that there is no gap between the two columns. The pdf looks much like the one above, except some have more rows and the data without gaps is not always between the first and second row and is not only between zeroes

Comment: could you potentially share a couple of pages of the pdf? It would save me trying to recreate it myself badly. If you could include a bit where the data is linked, that would be great

Comment: I think you might find [this link about pdf structure](https://web.archive.org/web/20141010035745/http://gnupdf.org/Introduction_to_PDF) helpful.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/svuq0lgufcgsov3nf096w/structure.pdf?rlkey=y1f2ojvu049spof6mvj5fmhda&dl=0

Is the link to the full pdf :) Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 1):

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
import pandas as pd
import re
reader = PdfReader("structure.pdf")

lines = []
# get the lines of text for every page
for page in reader.pages[2:]:
    text = page.extract_text().split("\n")
    lines.extend(text)

# initialise the dataframe
out = pd.DataFrame({
})
molecule = ""
abbreviation = ""

for line in lines[3:]:
    print(line)
    # if line ends with a colon, then it's a molecule
    if line.endswith(":"):
        abbreviation, molecule = re.split(r",(?!\d)", line[1:-1])

    # if it's not a page number, then it's a line of data
    elif not re.match(r"^S\d+$", line):
        vals = line.split()
        cleaned_vals = []
        # deal with the messy lines of data
        for val in vals:
            # if it's two joined numbers, split them
            if len(val) > 18:
                val = re.split(r"(?=\d\.\d+)", val)[1:]
                cleaned_vals.extend(val)
            # otherwise, just append it
            else:
                cleaned_vals.append(val)

        # append to the dataframe
        out = out._append({
            'abbreviation' : abbreviation,
            'molecule' : molecule,
            'a' : float(cleaned_vals[0]),
            'b' : float(cleaned_vals[1]),
            'c' : float(cleaned_vals[2]),
            'd' : cleaned_vals[3]
        }, ignore_index=True)
>>> out
    abbreviation            molecule         a         b         c  d
0             CO     Carbon monoxide  0.000000  0.000000  0.915905  o
1             CO     Carbon monoxide  0.000000  0.000000 -1.221207  c
2             CS   Carbon monosulﬁde  0.000000  0.000000 -2.117775  c
3             CS   Carbon monosulﬁde  0.000000  0.000000  0.794165  s
4             H2          Dihydrogen  0.000000  0.000000  0.701835  h
..           ...                 ...       ...       ...       ... ..
841        C2H6O      Dimethyl ether  1.684678  2.325771 -1.585849  h
842        C2H6O      Dimethyl ether -1.684678  2.325771 -1.585849  h
843        C2H6O      Dimethyl ether  0.000000  3.819813  0.925699  h
844        C2H6O      Dimethyl ether -1.684678 -2.325771 -1.585849  h
845        C2H6O      Dimethyl ether  1.684678 -2.325771 -1.585849  h

[846 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will have a look :)